# VBA Filter for Yesterday after a Specific Time until Today at a Specific Time in two Different Columns

Tags: excel, vba, filter, timestamp, autofilter

I've been trying this for hours now with no luck. I have a large data set. In column P I have only dates (mm/dd/yyyy). In column Q I have the time Stamp (hh:mm:ss). I'm trying to write a code that will Filter Column P for Yesterday (considering business days only) and Today. But, here's the trick. I need to consider only the information for Yesterday after 14:01:01 and Today until 14:00:00.

I basically don't know how to do it, I was writing code when I figured that having the time stamp on a different column was ruining my results because it is an independent variable. I tried concatenating but then figured out it was a dead end.

Any help or guidance will be much appreciated.

Thanks

This is where I stopped and decided to ask for guidance

```
 Set ws = ActiveSheet
    ws.Activate 'not required but allows user to view sheet if warning message appears
    
      'Clear any existing filters
    On Error Resume Next
    ws.ShowAllData
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    'Apply Filters
    On Error Resume Next
    With Range("A:Q")
        .AutoFilter
    End With
    
    Dim PreviousDate As String
    Dim TodayDate As String
    
    'Previous working day us this one :
    PreviousDate = Format(CDate(Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Date, -1)), "mm/dd/yyyy")
    TodayDate = Format(CDate(Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Date, 0)), "mm/dd/yyyy")
   
    '1. Apply Filter
    On Error Resume Next
    With Range("A:Q")
        .AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria2:=Array(2, PreviousDate, 2, TodayDate), Operator:=xlFilterValues, Operator:=xlAnd
        .AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria2:=Array(3, ">=14:00:00"), Operator:=xlFilterValues, Operator:=xlAnd
        End With
    On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that Autofilter with a separate date and a time column: you need to combine them and filter on the combined column.